# Is it correct to use ''scores of (something)'' with uncountable nouns?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

''Score of something'' means ''a lot of something.'' Although it is correct to use ''a lot of'' with uncountable nouns, I've never seen an example of ''scores of something'' used with an uncountable noun in a dictionary. So, is it correct to use ''scores of (something)'' with uncountable nouns ?

Definition of ''score of something'' in Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English is ''a lot of people or things'' For instance,

Scores of victims were killed.

Comment: A 'score of some things' means 'twenty of those things'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey LDOCE defines score of something as ''a lot of people or things''

Comment: LDOCE is giving an informal meaning.

Answer (score 5):

No, it isn't correct, because **a score** means twenty. If there are 'scores of things', there are so many you can count them in twenties. Obviously, this doesn't make sense with uncountable nouns.

Answer (score 2):

A score of  means 'a group of 20 things'. The things have to be countable. We wouldn't say 'hundreds of water' or 'dozens of coal'.

> Definition of score
>
> a: TWENTY
>
> b: a group of 20 things —often used in combination with a cardinal
> number
> *fourscore*

[Score (Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/score)

Answer (score 0):

"Score" is informally used as a synonym for "twenty". In this context, a score of something would *not* make sense.